# Android Speech Recogntion won't work in a separate class

Tags: java, android, adapter, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I'm a beginner in Android development. What I'm trying to create is an app the speaks to you then waits for your answer so its kind of text to speech works ,then it activates speech recognition and *with my code the text to speech works then it calls speech recognition*.Then an erro msg is shown ,the catch block is executed.
The problem is that I have to add Speech Recognition in a separate class, then add an Object of it in the Adapter not Main Activity. Speech Recognition won't work and since all tutorials for speech recognition for Android are adding the code in Main Activity and I'm doing it as class called in the adapter is the problem  ?

**UPDATE startActivityForResult() method is not working**

**Here is the code for SpeechRecogntion class**

```
public class SpeechRecog extends Activity   {

    private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;
    String textResult ;

    public void Start (Intent i , Context c){
        i  = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Are You Done ,  yet? ");

        try{
            startActivityForResult(i,VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE); 
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(c, "SpeechRecogntion is not avalible on your device ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if ((requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE)&& (resultCode== RESULT_OK)) {
            textResult= data.getStringExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            if (checkResult())
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are done ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are not done ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private boolean checkResult() {
        if (textResult.equals("done")||(textResult.equals("yes")))
            return true ; 

        return false;
    }
}
```

**And Here is the object of it in the Adapter class**

```
private SpeechRecog mySP; 
private Intent mySpIntetn ;

    public ListAdapterClass(Context context) {
        mytts = new TxtToSpeechClass(context); 
        mySP = new SpeechRecog();
    }
```

**And Here is where my problem relies ,the on clicklistener inside the Adapter class**

```
Lh.btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if (Lh.btn.getText().equals("Play"))
        {
            Lh.btn.setText("Pause"); //change the btn status so user know how to stop it 

            List<Items> hResults=db.getAllItems(Lh.idList + 1);    

            for (int i = 0; i < hResults.size(); i++) 
            {
                Items item = hResults.get(i);
                String s = item.getItemname();  
                mytts.Talk(s,1);

                mySP.Start(mySpIntetn , context ); //the code in here wont work is there something I'm missing here 

                Toast.makeText(context,s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            mytts.Talk("Congrats  ",1);// 1 means Queue_add

        } else {
            Lh.btn.setText("Play");
            mytts.Talk("See you later", 0); // 0 means Queue_Flush
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: And what doesn't work?

Comment: Well the Speech Recognition doesn't work..

Comment: startActivityForResult() for Speech recognition is showing error can you check it out?

Answer (score 0):

`mySpIntetn` is private. Try to change it to public in the Adapter class.

Comment: What does LogCat say?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)
 at com.example.vozapplication.SpeechRecog.Start(SpeechRecog.java:24)
 E/AndroidRuntime(413): at com.example.vozapplication.ListAdapterClass$1.onClick(ListAdapterClass.java:117)

Comment: SpeechRecog(Activity).startActivityForResult(Intent, int, Bundle) line: 3446 
SpeechRecog(Activity).startActivityForResult(Intent, int) line: 3407 
SpeechRecog.Start(Intent, Context) line: 24

Comment: And what is the line 24 in SpeechRecog.java? The NPE stack trace doesn't seem to match the code you shared.

Comment: I was using getApplicaionContext(), now I passing it to Start() method.This made my app work but SR is still not working . There is a problem in  startActivityForResult(i,VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE); it always show the error msg I'm putting in Try catch